# How to run CMake with predetermined settings?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

In Visual Studio, a project using CMake will have a CMakeSettings.json file that specifies the command line parameters to be used. In IDEs other than Visual Studio, how do I control which parameters CMake is run with?

Assuming CMake is run from the project root, I want CMake initialization to be run like this:
cmake -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug

And I want CMake building to run like this:
cmake --build build

**My project structure looks like this:**

```
project/  
|- bin/  
|   |- program (executable)  
|- build/  
|   |- ... CMake files ...  
|- src/  
|   |- program.c  
|   |- CMakeLists.txt  
|- CMakeLists.txt
```

**project/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)  
 project(Project VERSION 1.0)  
 file(MAKE_DIRECTORY bin)  
 add_subdirectory(src)
```

**project/src/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
 set(TARGET_NAME program)
 file(GLOB_RECURSE FILES *.c)
 add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${FILES})
 file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/${TARGET_NAME})
 set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY             
 ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/${TARGET_NAME})
```

I understand that developers might want to use a different IDEs other than Visual Studio. Would it be a good idea to have a command line script to run CMake commands properly? My goal is to be able to have a developer download my project and have it build and run with their IDE with minimal setup.

Comment: As a Visual Studio user I would not want to build debug only.  I usually build Debug and Release and sometimes RelWithDebugInfo with my CMake generated projects.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, that was just an example. Ideally, I'd want to be able to build with Debug and Release and x64 and x86 architectures. That might be beyond the scope of what I can make common between generated project files, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In IDEs other than Visual Studio, how do I control which parameters CMake is run with?

Depends on what IDE you are using. There is no standard way. Typically, there is a settings form.

A good solution is to document the command line commands that should be used. And ideally, those commands should be as conventional as possible, such as those that you quoted in the question, so that anyone who can already use CMake is able to compile the program without the help of an IDE and even without reading the documentation.

You could write a trivial POSIX shell script to run those commands, which can be convenient and can work as the documentation (as long as you describe its purpose in the readme file).